# Open a new file from command line on os/x using default application for the file type

Tags: macos, command-line

This should be quite simple .. but is not working

```
open x.txt
```

Just hangs using `iTerm2`.  The default app should be TextEdit.app. So how to do this?

Note: I have also tried

```
open -a TextEdit.app x.txt
```

with same behavior (hanging)

On `Terminal` the following occurs:

```
 $o x.txt
 The file /Users/steboesch/x.txt does not exist.
```

Comment: If you choose Get Info for your text file (in Finder), does TextEdit show up as the [registered (Open With) app](http://osxdaily.com/2011/02/01/change-default-app-file-opens-with-mac/)?

Comment: Try calling x.txt with absolute path **open PATH/x.txt**. It works for me

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like  With a non-existent file? Really? That does not work for me  for either TextPad or jEdit

Comment: @javadba Oopsss....not for a non existent file. Got your question now, let me see

Comment: Not a direct answer, but a workaround: you could create the file using "touch x.txt" or "echo blah > x.txt" before invoking open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you  are trying to run doesn't work because, till the time of this writing (**OSX 10.10.4**) is still using **Open(1)**

Look at the screenshots below for difference

[image]

Here is a screenshot of man page for open in CentOS 7, using **Open(2)**

[image]

With the above situation, you can try workarounds.

Here is what i would do:

```
touch newfile.txt && open -e newfile.txt
```

Comment: actually should be "&&" - to run the second command if the first one succeeded =  not "|"  ;)

Comment: I am going to award since you definitively uncovered the underlying mechanisms of why/where open were not working. Nice sleuthing.